# postgres large table select optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

I have to extract DB to external DB server for licensed software.
DB has to be Postgres and I cannot change select query from application (cannot change source code).

Table (it has to be 1 table) holds around 6,5M rows and has unique values in main column (prefix).

All requests are read request, no inserts/update/delete, and there are ~200k selects/day with peaks of 15 TPS.

Select query is:

```
SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff FROM table 
WHERE '00436641997142' LIKE prefix 
AND company = 0  and ((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null)) and (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0  or "Day" is null )  
ORDER BY position('%' in prefix) ASC, char_length(prefix) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Explain analyze shows following

```
Limit  (cost=406433.75..406433.75 rows=1 width=113) (actual time=1721.360..1721.361 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=406433.75..406436.72 rows=1188 width=113) (actual time=1721.358..1721.358 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ("position"((prefix)::text, '%'::text)), (char_length(prefix)) DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..406427.81 rows=1188 width=113) (actual time=1621.159..1721.345 rows=1 loops=1)
              Filter: ((company = 0) AND ('00381691997142'::text ~~ (prefix)::text) AND ((strpos(("Day")::text, (to_char(now(), 'ID'::text))::text) > 0) OR ("Day" IS NULL)) AND (((('now'::cstring)::time with time zone >= (timefrom)::time with time zone) AN (...)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 6417130
Planning time: 0.165 ms
Execution time: 1721.404 ms`
```

Slowest part of query is:

```
 SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff FROM table 
 WHERE '00436641997142' LIKE prefix
```

which generates 1,6s (tested only this part of query)

Part of query tested separately:

```
Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..181819.07 rows=32086 width=113) (actual time=1488.359..1580.607 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: ('004366491997142'::text ~~ (prefix)::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 6417130
Planning time: 0.061 ms
Execution time: 1580.637 ms
```

About data itself:
column "prefix" has identical first several digits (first 5) and rest are different, unique ones.

Postgres version is 9.5
I've changed following settings of Postgres:

```
random-page-cost = 40
effective_cashe_size = 4GB
shared_buffer = 4GB
work_mem = 1GB
```

I have tried with several index types (unique, gin, gist, hash), but in all cases indexes are not used (as stated in explain above) and result speed is same.
I've also did, but no visible improvements:

```
vacuum analyze verbose table
```

Please recommend settings of DB and/or index configuration in order to speed up execution time of this query.

Current HW is 
i5, SSD, 16GB RAM on Win7, but I have option to buy stronger HW.
As I understood, for cases where read (no inserts/updates) is dominant, faster CPU cores are much more important than number of cores or disk speed > please, confirm.

Add-on 1:
After adding 9 indexes, index is not used also.

Add-on 2:
1) I found out reason for not using index: word order in query in part like is reason. if query would be:

```
SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff FROM table WHERE prefix like '00436641997142%'
AND company = 0  and 
((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null)) and (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0  or "Day" is null )
 ORDER BY position('%' in prefix) ASC, char_length(prefix) DESC LIMIT 1
```

it uses index.

notice difference:

```
... WHERE '00436641997142%' like prefix ...
```

query which uses index correctly:

```
... WHERE prefix like '00436641997142%' ...
```

since I cannot change query itself, any idea how to overcome this? I can change data and Postgres settings, but not query itself.

2) Also, I intalled Postgres 9.6 version in order to use parallel seq.scan. In this case, parallel scan is used only if last part of query is ommited. So, query:

```
SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff FROM table WHERE '00436641997142' LIKE prefix 
AND company = 0  and 
((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null))
 ORDER BY position('%' in prefix) ASC, char_length(prefix) DESC LIMIT 1
```

uses parallel mode.

Any idea how to force original query (I cannot change query):

```
SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff FROM erm_table WHERE '00436641997142' LIKE prefix 
AND company = 0  and 
((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null)) and (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0  or "Day" is null )
 ORDER BY position('%' in prefix) ASC, char_length(prefix) DESC LIMIT 1
```

to use parallel seq. scan?

Comment: Is there any reasons why you are using `like` instead of `=`?

Comment: I cannot change it > it is in source code to which I don't have access. Query with "=" instead of "like" is 3x faster, but I cannot change it

Comment: `random-page-cost = 40` why that high? On an SSD ...

Comment: default was 4, and I increased to see is there any difference.  basically response time is same as for 4 or 8

Comment: You could try to lower it to 1.1 or so, but I'm afraid it wont help (there are no usable indexes on a LIKE '%literal' query)

Comment: BTW: you could get rid of the OR in the where aluse by updating SET time_FROM = '-infinity' where time_from IS NULL (and similar for time_to = '+infinity'), but don't do this on production database...

Comment: I've just tested with random-page-cost=1.1 result is same (~1,7s query time)  
About, OR > I agree, but I cannot change query at all

Comment: I've just added > query speed is same (most time is consumed for prefix column)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. What happens if you remove `'00436641997142' LIKE prefix` part from your original query? Is there any index used? What number of the rows returned? Because the proper filtering by other conditions could extremely reduce the number of rows which should be checked by `prefix`.

Comment: it doesn't use index
query speed is ~27s
all other fields are totally same (except prefix column)

Comment: And how many rows it returns? Try to optimize this part of the query. I dont know any way to optimize conditions like `const LIKE column` (without changing query/data structure/application logic).

Comment: `Filter: ('00381691997142'::text ~~ (prefix)::text)` The only crazy plan I can invent is to use partitioning (into 10 tables, starting with 0..9) [BTW: I've never used partitioning]

Comment: ok, thx. I will
my question was also in general about performance (not only optimizing like query), meaning > would SAS disks or Xeon CPU or forcing somehow DB to be more in RAM improve performance? or some other idea (except query itself)

Comment: What is the *typical* value for prefix? for example: does it always start with numeric characters?

Comment: yes, always numeric and even more> first 5 digits are always same; rest are different

Comment: You could try with a bunch of partial indexes: `create index xx6 ON ztable (prefix) where prefix >= '003816' AND prefix < '003817';` etc.

Comment: I've just created 9 indexed and tested > it still does seq. scan and query time is same (1.7s)

Comment: 1) did you run analyze after creating the 9 indexes ? 2) your work_mem=1GB is insanely large. 3) add some more info about your table, especially the contents of valid_from and valid_upto

Comment: I've added in expain result in initial post; basically it is not using index still. I was playing around with planner, and put very high cost of seq. scan, but still it doesn't use index.   I tried on different machine (i3, normal HDD), and result is 2x slower, aroun 3.5s.  Currently I am considering buying much stronger HW to speed up result query

Comment: Without changing the query, I'm not sure there is a solution to your problem. If you are using licensed software, maybe you should ask the vendor to fix the issue?  In any case, I started a bounty on your question so that it gets more attention.  Who knows, maybe someone out there does know of a workaround that will work for you.

Comment: As noted @Abelisto , your request is incorrect, you are comparing a constant '00436641997142%', the result should be 0 matches found.
Although if you have a record '00436641997142%', then  found 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too hard to make an index for queries like `strin LIKE pattern` because wildcards (% and _) can stand everywhere.

I can suggest one risky solution:

1. Slightly redesign the table - make it indexable. Add two more column `prefix_low` and `prefix_high` of fixed width - for example `char(32)`, or any arbitrary length enough for the task. Also add one `smallint` column for prefix length. Fill them with lowest and highest values matching prefix and prefix length.  For example:

   ```
   select rpad(rtrim('00436641997142%','%'), 32, '0') AS prefix_low, rpad(rtrim('00436641997142%','%'), 32, '9') AS prefix_high, length(rtrim('00436641997142%','%')) AS prefix_length;

          prefix_low                 |               prefix_high             |   prefix_length
   ----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----
    00436641997142000000000000000000 | 00436641997142999999999999999999      |   14
   ```
2. Make index with these values

   ```
   CREATE INDEX table_prefix_low_high_idx ON table (prefix_low, prefix_high);
   ```
3. Check modified requests against table:

   ```
   SELECT prefix, changeprefix, deletelast, outgroup, tariff 
   FROM table 
   WHERE '00436641997142%' BETWEEN prefix_low AND prefix_high
     AND company = 0  
     AND ((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null)) and (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0  or "Day" is null )
   ORDER BY prefix_length DESC 
   LIMIT 1
   ```

   Check how well it works with indexes, try to tune it - add/remove index for prefix_length add it to between index and so on.
4. Now you need to rewrite queries to database. Install PgBouncer and [PgBouncer-RR patch](https://github.com/awslabs/pgbouncer-rr-patch). It allows you rewrite queries on-fly with easy python code like in example:

   ```
   import re

   def rewrite_query(username, query):
      q1=r"""^SELECT [^']*'(?P<id>\d+)%'[^'] ORDER BY (?P<position>\('%' in prefix\) ASC, char_length\(prefix\) LIMIT """
      if not re.match(q1, query):
         return query  # nothing to do with other queries
      else:
         new_query = # ... rewrite query here
      return new_query
   ```
5. Run pgBouncer and connect it to DB. Try to issue different queries like your application does and check how they are getting rewrited. Because you deal with text you have to tweak regexps to match all required queries and rewrite them properly.
6. When proxy is ready and debugged reconnect your application to pgBouncer.

Pro:

- no changes to application
- no changes to basic structure of DB

Contra:

- extra maintenance - you need triggers to keep all new columns with actual data
- extra tools to support
- rewrite uses regexp so it's closely tied to particular queries issued by your app. You need to run it for some time and make robust rewrite rules.

Further development:
 highjack parsed query tree in pgsql itself https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Query_Parsing

Comment: many thanks for idea and answer
this will help me a lot > I will implement and test it; but basically idea is perfect; thx

Comment: instead of creating additional column for prefix length, you can create index  for it. `CREATE INDEX table_prefix_length_idx ON table (char_length(prefix))`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, creating proxy server which rewrites queries could be solution here.

Here is an [example from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550381/5932498).

Then you could change "LIKE" to "=" in your query, and it would run a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your index by adding proper operator class, according to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-opclass.html):

> The operator classes text_pattern_ops, varchar_pattern_ops, and
>   bpchar_pattern_ops support B-tree indexes on the types text, varchar,
>   and char respectively. The difference from the default operator
>   classes is that the values are compared strictly character by
>   character rather than according to the locale-specific collation
>   rules. This makes these operator classes suitable for use by queries
>   involving pattern matching expressions (LIKE or POSIX regular
>   expressions) when the database does not use the standard "C" locale.
>   As an example, you might index a varchar column like this:
>
> `CREATE INDEX test_index ON test_table (col varchar_pattern_ops);`

Comment: I've just added it with:

    CREATE INDEX test_index ON erm_table (prefix bpchar_pattern_ops);
since prefix field is character type
but, query speed is same > 1,7s

Comment: have you dropped the old one? set SET enable_seqscan = OFF; for testing

Comment: I've posted analyzer in initial post; basically, result is same, and seq. scan is used although it is put to off (strange?)

Comment: ok, now I have red the whole query. The problem could be somewhere else, expressions like those: (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0 are black boxes for optimizer. maybe try just for verification to add a partial index with that in where clause: ((current_time between timefrom and timeto) or (timefrom is null and timeto is null)) and (strpos("Day", cast(to_char(now(), 'ID') as varchar)) > 0  or "Day" is null )

Comment: I deleted completely that part of query and performance result is same (I put in initial post result of analyzer without and other clause in where except prefix part)

Comment: I don't think you can create a partial index that references current_time